# Rearanging Six Variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

$$
\begin{align}    
   x & =\frac{R+\frac{G+B}{-2}}{R+G+B} \\[10pt]
    y & =\frac{\frac{(G-B) \sqrt{3}}{2}}{R+G+B} \\[10pt]
    L & =\frac{56(\frac{R}{255})^{2.2}+181(\frac{G}{255})^{2.2}+18(\frac{B}{255})^{2.2}}{255}
\end{align}
$$

Here's what I got:
$$R=2 x +1$$ $$G=  y\sqrt{3} -x+1$$ $$B=-x-y\sqrt{3} +1$$

The problem is that R G and B do not turn out to be the right numbers. However, They are the **right ratio**. For example, using **RGB=(255,128,64)** , I converted to **xyL=(0.36,0.12,0.37)** , then back... I get **RGB=(55.1,27.7,13.8)** . This is about 4.6x too small with the same ratio. So I need to multiply RGB by some variable, I just don't know what. It's soo simple, I just can't think of it. This is every color on a Cartesian plane and L is perceived lucence.

Comment: I don't see $z$ defined anywhere, but you use it in your last three expressions.  What is $z$?

Comment: I fixed the $z$ and $L$ issues. thanks @MatthewConroy

Comment: Your formulas for $R$, $G$, $B$ do not include $L$, that's why. It would be much simpler if you applied the gamma correction to $L$ instead of each component, i.e.$$L(R,G,B) = \left ( \frac{56}{255}\frac{R}{255} + \frac{181}{255}\frac{G}{255} + \frac{18}{255}\frac{B}{255} \right )^{2.2}$$because then $L$ would just scale $R$, $G$, and $B$ (by $L^{1/2.2}=L^{5/11}\approx L^{0.4545}$). Right now, $L$ also affects the ratios between $R$, $G$, and $B$, and is nasty to calculate correctly.

Comment: Question: Why do you only apply gamma correction when calculating $L$? Gamma correction does affect $x$ and $y$, too, after all.

Comment: Cool you noticed that I'm doing this for gamma. I'm using $L$ as perceived brightness so it is the only thing really affected by gamma. $x$ and $y$ are(is) just a 2d location of the ratio of R:G:B and do not change location just because it is brighter or darker. In other words 'orange is orange no matter how bright'. I want all colors that have the same $L$ to be the same perceived brightness.

Comment: You're wrong; gamma correction does affect $x$ and $y$, especially for dark (low-L) colors. Consider $R=51$ (20%), $G=153$ (60%), $B=51$ (20%): with no gamma correction, $x=-0.2$ and $y=0.346$. With gamma correction of 2.2, $x=-0.386$ and $y=0.669$. Either do it properly, or don't do it at all. It's only when you do it partially/wrong (gamma-correct $R$,$G$,$B$ only for $L$), that the equations are so nasty.

Comment: You are right about doing it right the first time. However, I did not feel like I was taking the wrong approach.

Comment: Opinion does not matter. Do not let your ego blind you. Your assumption that *"$L$ as perceived brightness is the only thing really affected by gamma"* is provably incorrect, as demonstrated above: gamma correction affects $x$ and $y$ **significantly**. Sure, you can calculate your colorspace any way you want, but it will be an arbitrary choice; not based on physics and/or perception, unlike just about every other color model in existence. For me, the interesting bit is that your way is also more computationally intensive, for no gain whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$M$ is the biggest $L$ can be, so $R$ $G$ and $B$ need to be scaled down from what I had (in my question, $M$), to the current $L$ value.
$$M=(L/((56((2x+1)/3)^{2.2}+181((-x+y\sqrt{3}+1)/3)^{2.2}+18((-x-y\sqrt{3}+1)/3)^{2.2})/255))$$

$$R=255(((\frac{2x+1}{3})^{2.2}*M)^{\frac{1}{2.2}})$$
$$G=255(((\frac{-x+y\sqrt{3}+1}{3})^{2.2}*M)^{\frac{1}{2.2}})$$
$$B=255(((\frac{-x-y\sqrt{3}+1}{3})^{2.2}*M)^{\frac{1}{2.2}})$$

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to consider a slightly different approach, one that applies the gamma correction consistently. If the original components are $0 \le R, G, B \le 255$, and gamma correction is $a$, then use intermediate components
$$\begin{cases}
r = \left ( \frac{R}{255} \right )^a \\
g = \left ( \frac{G}{255} \right )^a \\
b = \left ( \frac{B}{255} \right )^a
\end{cases} \iff \begin{cases}
R = 255 \; r^{1/a} \\
G = 255 \; g^{1/a} \\
B = 255 \; b^{1/a}
\end{cases}$$
Note that this allows you to use different gamma corrections for the three components, if you want. In practice, look-up tables are usually precomputed for each component. (The forward conversion obviously only takes 256 entries, but for the inverse, you might wish to use more entries to retain the entire dynamic range.)

The conversion using the intermediate components is then
$$\begin{cases}
x = \frac{r - \frac{g + b}{2}}{r + g + b} \\
y = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\frac{g - b}{r + g + b} \\
L = \frac{56}{255}r + \frac{181}{255}g + \frac{18}{255}b
\end{cases} \iff \begin{cases}
r = L \frac{1 + 2 x}{\sqrt{3}\frac{163}{255} y - \frac{87}{255} x + 1 }\\
g = L \frac{1 - x + \sqrt{3}y}{\sqrt{3}\frac{163}{255} y - \frac{87}{255} x + 1 }\\
b = L \frac{1 - x - \sqrt{3}y}{\sqrt{3}\frac{163}{255} y - \frac{87}{255} x + 1 }
\end{cases}$$